# Is there any way I can use regular dremel bits on a dremel trio?

Tags: powertools

A few years ago I bought a [Dremel Trio](http://www.dremel.com/en-us/tools/pages/tooldetail.aspx?pid=6800), which uses much more expensive bits than a regular Dremel.  The collets are also different.  Consequently I never really used it.

Now I'm making a custom cnc machine, and I would like to use the Trio for the actual cutting device.  However Dremel does not make a collet adapter that will allow me to use regular bits in the Trio.

Does anyone know of a universal collet adapter, or anything like that?  It seems that there would be a simple way to solve this problem, but for the life of me I can't think of it.

Comment: A picture of the collet would be helpful. Is it a variant on a standard 1/4" collet, some weird variant on same, or built in and unremovable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dremel don't support that

[Here](http://www.dremel.com/en-us/customerservice/productsupport/faq/Pages/FAQDetail.aspx?prod=Trio) are the reasons they give:

> Q: **Can the Dremel Trio use Dremel rotary tool accessories?**
>
> A: No. Though Trio accessories look and work like standard rotary tool accessories, they are specially engineered to handle the demands placed upon them by this slower yet more powerful tool.
>
> Q: **What is the difference between rotary tool and Trio Accessories?**
>
> A: The Dremel Trio only accepts accessories with 3/16” shanks. Rotary tools, on the other hand, use accessories with shank diameters ranging from of 1/8” to 1/32”. This means you can’t use Trio accessories in your Dremel rotary tool – and you can’t use rotary tool accessories in your Trio (and there are no “conversion collets” available allowing you to do so).

The rotary tools have high speed (e.g. 30,000 RPM) but low-torque motors. Maybe the Trio is different and might break bits designed for low-torque tools (or at least, Dremel wish to avoid being held responsible for any consequences of large numbers of bit breakages)

Comment: I saw that - it always seemed a bit contrived, or at least not relevent in this actual case, which is a bit unusual.

Comment: I've done more research, and it seems there really is no good, safe way to do this.

Comment: I also have the Trio, and now it's impossible to find bits for it.  Anyone knows where to get compatible bits?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an aftermarket collet available here:

https://www.testntools.co.nz/dremel-trio-collet-adapter-for-3.2mm-1-8-shank-accessories-t000000001.html

Answer (score 0):

You can take the collet out of your rotary (if you have one) and put it inside the collet that is on the Trio. This will now hold all rotary shanks in the Trio.